# Merge json array elements with jq

Tags: json, edit, jq, string-concatenation

I want to merge array values using jq.
In my input json there's an array `times` of nested arrays, each having (always) two string elements. I want those two string elements concatenated and the nested array removed so that there's ony one array left:

My input:

```
{
   "times":[
      [
         "7:29", "IN"
      ],
      [
         "10:29", "OUT"
      ]
   ],
   "foo":"bar"
}
```

My desired output is:

```
{
   "times":
   [
         "7:29 IN", "10:29 OUT"
   ],
   "foo":"bar"
}
```

This is how I merged the array elements, what's missing is to make a json array from it again:

```
jq    '.times | to_entries | .[] | (.value[0]+ " " + .value[1])'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
jq '.times |= map(join(" "))' file
```

yields:

```
{
  "times": [
    "7:29 IN",
    "10:29 OUT"
  ],
  "foo": "bar"
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Was going for a `map(join(" "))` but this is way better!